# Custom view django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I have a view like this:

```
class VIewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('id', 'nome', 'cim', 'telefone', 'total_notas', 'credito', 'ativo')

def total_notas(self, obj):
    if obj.total_notas:
        return '<a href="??????">%s</a>' % (obj.total_notas())
total_notas.allow_tags = True

admin.site.register(Model, ViewAdmin)
```

I need to click in 'total_notes' and take to another view where I can just see only those registers

I want to write another view in the admin where I can display only those objects records..

total_notes show the total of notes and in the view that I need to write, should display that records.. how can I do that??

sorry about my english..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a filter?

If not just create the view and add an entry for it in urls.py. Then call it like:

```
def total_notas(self, obj):
    return '<a href="my_view/%s">%s</a>' % (self.total_notas)
```